# unwanted additional title area is added on all screen

Tags: codenameone

All of a sudden I noticed unwanted title area component on top of all forms.

It was not available before today and suddenly it appears on every form.

[image]

I also noticed that additional component on real device too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the dropshadow for the `TitleArea` UIID. We mentioned this in the blog [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/library-update-nativeinterface-generics.html):

> We just updated the library with our last ad hoc release, starting
>   next week we will release libraries every Friday and occasionally also
>   a plugin update within that same proximity. We made some refinements
>   to some Android theme elements and one of those refinements is a new
>   TitleArea drop shadow.
>
> This effectively creates a situation where we can’t reasonably detect
>   an empty title and so if you want the title to truly disappear you can
>   either:
>
> - Set the TitleArea border attribute to empty
> - Do something like form.getToolbar().setUIID("Container")

Comment: its working but in addition to that I would like to add for other users that also set padding & margin to 0 otherwise still it will occupy some space. Thanks.